# Is there a difference between $(el).on(...) or $(document).on(el, ...) for attaching a listener?

Tags: jquery

Two formats:

`$(document).on('click', ".class", ...)`

and

`$('.class').on('click', ...`

Are there any differences, and is either preferred over the other? Or are they the same thing?

Comment: Did you read the documentation, which explains at great length what each one does?

Comment: You should read: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 1, only the `document` has been given the instruction; it is responsible for noticing clicks on behalf of its child elements. The work of catching events has been delegated. It's called as **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

In case 2, each of those elements with class named `class` has been individually given instructions. If new `.class` get dynamically created, they won't be able to respond to any event such as `click` in your case.

So basically, use event delegation when your elements has been added dynamically to the DOM and use direct click handler for existed elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the first, you don't know whether `.class` is there or not.

But in the second, you know that it is there is that DOM element.It just behaves like `.bind()`

So

1.Use 1st format, when you dynamically appending elements.

2.Use 2nd format, if you know that the element is already present in the DOM